# How to get speech also in audio file in botframework using directline?

Tags: botframework, speech, direct-line-botframework

I am using botframework channel directline in C# for my chatbot recently I added Bing speech for text to speech and vice versa but is there any chance that when user speaks to have beside plain text also the audio file as attachment in message activity.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: You can access audio and video with a skype bot https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-real-time-audio-video-call-overview

Comment: did u ever got a solution fr this

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 2):

In the case of the Webchat channel, you can have a look to the sources to understand how it is using speech recognition.

In particular, you can see that all speech part is made by the webchat before sending the message to the bot ([sources](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/src/Store.ts#L578)):

```
const startListeningEpic: Epic<ChatActions, ChatState> = (action$, store) =>
    action$.ofType('Listening_Starting')
    .do((action : ShellAction) => {
        var locale = store.getState().format.locale;
        var onIntermediateResult = (srText : string) => { store.dispatch({ type: 'Update_Input', input: srText, source:"speech" })};
        var onFinalResult = (srText : string) => {
                srText = srText.replace(/^[.\s]+|[.\s]+$/g, "");
                onIntermediateResult(srText);
                store.dispatch({ type: 'Listening_Stop' });
                store.dispatch(sendMessage(srText, store.getState().connection.user, locale));
            };
        var onAudioStreamStart = () => { store.dispatch({ type: 'Listening_Start' }) };
        var onRecognitionFailed = () => { store.dispatch({ type: 'Listening_Stop' })};
        Speech.SpeechRecognizer.startRecognizing(locale, onIntermediateResult, onFinalResult, onAudioStreamStart, onRecognitionFailed);
    })
    .map(_ => nullAction)
```

Here the bot code on the web app is called with `sendMessage(srText...`, without audio.

Comment: So what do u suggest can i modify that to add also the voice as attachment ??

Comment: What do you want to do with the audio?

Comment: I am trying to find a way to add avatar to chatbot!